# CurrentUser() return null in android after the login of the user in parse sdk

Tags: javascript, java, android, vue.js, parse-platform

I'm creating an app with VuejS and cordova (full javascript) for the front en Parse as back-end.

I'm trying to connect the user after login or sign up (done in the front) with the device he's using.

So in my MainActivity in android, i added

```
 ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        ParseUser user  = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (installation != null && user != null) {
            installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            installation.saveInBackground();
        }
```

but the page doesn't reload after to add the user as a pointer, and also the currentUser is always null even after login.

I tried creatin an anonymous user and it works so why does it not for a normal user, i'm stuck.

tanks

Comment: Are you using Parse-Server-JS-SDK or using REST API ? And are you using Vue.js or Java ?

Comment: i'm using vuejs on my front end but when the app is launching, i have to use java in the MainActivity to save the installation class from the phone.

and 'im using  Parse-Server-JS-SDK

Comment: I even tried to get the user from a cloud function, and the result is null and m MainActivity while in my client it returns the user

Comment: Honestly I didn't get which platform you are using and what you are trying to do

Comment: I created an app full JS with vueJs and cordova plugin for the native part.

but for some functionallity, i had to modify the gradle file and the java files in cordova platform which is for android.